# How to Auto click the first search result in the following iframe?

Tags: html, javascript, google-sites, iframe

I have implemented an google search iframe on https://sites.google.com/view/fefv/home :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var myFrame = document.getElementById("myFrame");
        $(myFrame.contentWindow.document).find(h3.LC20lb.MBeuO.DKV0Md).on("click", function () { alert("clicked"); });
    });
</script>
    <iframe id="myFrame" src="https://www.google.com/search?q=domainate.top&igu=1"> </iframe>
```

my code autoclick code doesn't work.
I want to auto click the first search engine result and if possible open it in current window fully without iframe.please.